# How do I open Google Earth within a Python Kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to open Google Earth within my Python Kivy app. I have tried:

```
webbrowser.open ("https://www.google.com/earth/")
```

However, this opens Google Earth in a separate tab. I want it to open the link within the app rather than it redirecting elsewhere. Researching this I came across this code:

```
import kivy                                                                                     
from kivy.app import App                                                                        
from kivy.lang import Builder                                                                   
from kivy.utils import platform                                                                 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget                                                              
from kivy.clock import Clock                                                                    
from jnius import autoclass                                                                     
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread                                                   
                                                                                            
WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')                                                   
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')                                       
activity = 
autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity                              
                                                                                            
class Wv(Widget):                                                                               
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                               
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)                                                      
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)                                             
                                                                                            
    @run_on_ui_thread                                                                           
    def create_webview(self, *args):                                                            
        webview = WebView(activity)                                                             
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)                                        
        wvc = WebViewClient();                                                                  
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);                                                          
        activity.setContentView(webview)                                                        
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com')
                                                                                            
class ServiceApp(App):                                                                          
    def build(self):                                                                            
        return Wv()                                                                             
                                                                                            
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
     ServiceApp().run()
```

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser

However, this will not let me make this import statement:

```
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'android'
```

Comment: it would need widget which can display HTML. Other GUIs (like PyQt) often use widget `WebKit` for this - as I know even `Chrome` started as `WebKit` modification.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the source of the error in running that important statement